# Replace multiple char in a row with one in a Python string

Tags: python, string, replace

Let's say I have a string `a = "a*****cd"`. Is there a way to turn it into `"a*cd"` for any amount of "*" without multiple loops? "*" is the only character which needs to be 'condensed', so the solution doesn't have to be universal in this regard.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

### We can use a regular expression :

```
import re
a = "a***********cd"
a = re.sub("\*+", "*", a)
```

Let me explain :
`re.sub` function replaces all matches of the regular expression (first argument) : `"\*+"` (one or more asterix) with "*" (second argument) in the string  a (third argument)